# Super message count

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

Is there a way to see how many super messages are used on SFMC (including emails, cloud page impressions and anything else)?

note: The last question on this topic I could find is from 2016. I hope this functionality was introduced at some point.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not yet anything in the platform allowing you to view or query your current supermessage consumption

Comment: Thank you Lukas.